# Possible select query

Tags: mysql

I have 4 table like this :

- order
- customer_type
- type1
- type2

Every order has a customer which can be `type1` or `type2`.
In order table I have `customerId`, in customer_type I have `orderId` and the type of customer for that order.

My question is how can I get an order with his customer with only one select?

Comment: please provide table structure with detail

Comment: I think those are the only essential detail you need.Order table has details about Order and an Customer Id , Customer_Type table has Order Id and Type of Customer for that order and table type1 and type2 have only details about customer which are type1 or type2

Comment: My question is how can I get an order with his customer with only one select? nd what mean one select ?????? i didnt get your question

Comment: I meam something like select order.*,customer.* ... from ,because I founded a solution where I have two select with an union and try to get the order customer from every customer type table but is not ok because in time can appears many customer types

Comment: My tables are not like this. So we have order{Id,CustomerId,OrderDetails},customer_type{Id,CustomerType,OrderId},type1{I‌​d,CustomerDetails},type2{Id,CustomerDetails}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `union all` operator to make `type1` and `type2` act as one table, and from there it's just a series of `join`s:

```
SELECT order_details, customer_details
FROM   orders o
JOIN   customer_type ct ON o.customerId = ct.id
JOIN   (SELECT *, 'type1' AS type 
        FROM   type1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT *, 'type2' AS type 
        FROM   type2) t ON t.type = ct.type
```

Comment: My tables are not like this. So we have order{Id,CustomerId,OrderDetails},customer_type{Id,CustomerType,OrderId},type1{Id,CustomerDetails},type2{Id,CustomerDetails} and I want order and his customer

Comment: Just edit your question with the full description of the tables and the relationships between them, as @Affan asked originally, and then maybe we'll be able to help you.

Comment: Doesnt mater anymore,you give me an ideea with union all and I managed to apply it on my tables,so I will give you the corect answer.Thanks and sorry for the way I phrase the question.